Using a ConcreteModel as a Block in Pyomo Model
I'm looking for comments on this design pattern in pyomo.
In the case where we have models which can either be solved in isolation/separately or treated as a Block within a larger model, is there a downside to always building that sub-model as a ConcreteModel instead of a Block?
In this pattern the sub-model, call it sub is built as a class object and it would be nice to "anchor" the type as a ConcreteModel instead of doing some fancy factory thing where sometimes the production module/class outputs a ConcreteModel and sometimes (if intent is to attach it elsewhere) it produces a Block.  I note that ConcreteModel is a sub-class of Block, so this seems to make sense.
Does this design pattern fail in some way or is there some hidden overhead to just bypassing Block and using a ConcreteModel in lieu of Block?
A toy example.  Note that the top-level model appears happy to accept both a ConcreteModel and a Block as blocks.  In this case sub is just instantiated inline, in fuller example it would be a class
Code:
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# top level...
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# 2 sub-models, one itself a ConcreteModel, the other a Block
sub = pyo.ConcreteModel()
sub.X = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
sub.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sub.X)

other_sub = pyo.Block()
other_sub.Y = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
other_sub.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=other_sub.Y)

# stitch together...
m.sub = sub
m.other_sub = other_sub
m.sub.obj.deactivate()
m.other_sub.obj.deactivate()
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=m.sub.X + m.other_sub.Y)

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
res = opt.solve(m)

m.pprint()

I note that aside from the block references, the delta of the __dict__s is quite limited:
print(m.__dict__.keys() - other_sub.__dict__.keys())

{'sub', 'config', 'statistics', 'solutions', 'other_sub'}

